# Automatic homing on cobots after a collision

Tags: robotic-arm, precise-positioning, integration

I am in the midst of automating a mechanical process using a Dobot MG-400 cobot (in a lab setting, using a vision system to present a patient sample to a piece of sampling equipment). These arms are built with relative positional encoding and no automatic homing, so any time there is a collision we have to manually square each of the four joints. This has made path implementation and training very difficult and time consuming, as reproducibility is terrible before and after the collision (I have seen cartesian offsets greater than 4 mm near max reach). What has made matters worse is that all of the pose information that the arm outputs are based around hidden internal calculations that appear to be very sensitive to zero point errors. I built and implemented a homing switch cluster, but joint angle deviations measured at the cluster were not able to adjust the homing errors, likely due to the math that derived the pose joint angles instead of exposing actual encoder position.

**Griping aside, my question is: how common is it to find 4-6 axis arms without absolute positional encoders or homing switches?** Should a cobot be able to reset its home positions after a collision without assistance? I want to move from the Dobot into a more robust platform, but I am afraid of switching without these core issues being fixed. Would an arm from Universal Robotics or other common brands just not have this issue? Any advice or thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Once a relative encoder is homed, it should reflect the correct position, even after a collision. Unless there would be some mechanical displacement (e.g.slippage or a belt jumping one or more teeth) but in that case an absolute encoder would also indicate a wrong position. Maybe it does not have encoders at all (open loop stepper motors)?